# Can Baofeng UV-5R HTQ scan and handle TDR (split) mode at the same time?

Tags: baofeng

Today I received my first radiotelephone, Baofeng UV-5R HTQ. I saved some frequences and put the device in the MR mode. In one frequency, I make it scan through the saved frequencies, on the other one I'm tuned into a repeater. When I scan the frequencies and have TDR mode turned on, does it actually watch both the scanned frequency and the one I'm using on the other "slot"? I'm curious because I do hear the repeater transmissions, but I'm not sure if this is because I have it saved and I reached it while scanning, or because it's being monitored at the same time.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

The Baofeng UV-5R only has a single receiver and a single speaker.  If you have the dual watch (TDR) function turned on and then you activate scan, it may scan the programmed scan frequencies and also the frequency of the other VFO, but it's more likely that it only scans the programmed scan frequencies.  Different firmware versions may behave differently, so one firmware version may also scan the frequency of the other VFO, but another firmware version may not.

In my area there are many repeaters but not very much activity.  I use scan almost always.  The scan speed of the UV-5R is slow, so I only scan about six repeater frequencies.  To me the scan function is much more useful than the dual-watch (TDR) function.

I suggest that you experiment, and then post your results as an answer to your own question.

1. Remove the frequency of the other VFO from your scan frequencies
2. Activate dual-watch (TDR) mode
3. Activate scan
4. Have a friend transmit on the frequency of the other VFO.  Do you hear your friend?